# Duplicate Firebase Database key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, duplicates, key

I wanted to check what can cause this issue before reaching out to Firebase support. This is not the first time this has happened.

The keys are highlighted because I use the search function to confirm the keys are equal.

[image: duplication firebase key]

Comment: Hi. Are you adding these data manually in the console or programatically?

Comment: programmatically. I can post the code snippet if you'd like.

Comment: turns out there's firebase automatically truncates space.

Comment: the second keys were "358072046053457 "

Answer (score 0):

turns out there's firebase automatically truncates space. the second keys were "358072046053457 ".